A Guy Richie style action-comedy from the 90's about friends being chased by a hitman
What I remember, it's a not dark, more of a Guy Richie style film:
Genre : Action-Comedy
Country : Probably Germany
Release year : 1990's

Two friends, a girlfriend of one of them, a hitman and an accidentally replaced cellphone. 
The hitman doesn't speak (maybe at all) in the movie, He keeps chasing the guys and falls in love with the girlfriend of the one of the guys.
At the end of the movie, they tricked a gangster boss (probably the boss of the hitman) by faking death, but nobody dies in the entire movie.
The cellphones (of the hitman and the one of the guys) got swapped on a big train station.


Welcome to the community. Any other plot details?

Anybody? A wild guess?
